# Add attachment to github issue from the command line

Tags: github, command-line-interface

Is it possible to add an attachment to a GitHub issue from the command line?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The current official CLI (command line interface) [`cli/cli`](https://github.com/cli/cli) does not support [file attachment to issues](https://docs.github.com/en/github/managing-your-work-on-github/file-attachments-on-issues-and-pull-requests) (see [`gh issue`](https://cli.github.com/manual/gh_issue)).  7
Nor does the old CLI [`github/hub`](https://github.com/github/hub) (see [`hub issue`](https://hub.github.com/hub-issue.1.html))

Even the [GitHub API V3 for issues](https://developer.github.com/v3/issues/#create-an-issue) does not mention attachment.
So this is not available at the moment.

Answer (score 0):

I came across this command line tool that uses the private attachment API to do this: https://github.com/j178/github-s3